# Spring autowired injection fails for my annotated beans

Tags: spring, facelets, code-injection, autowired

I'm trying to autowire some beans together (I've created a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish) but I keep getting told the autowired bean is null.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bean.HelloWorld.getMessage(HelloWorld.java:15)
```

TestDAO.java

```
package dao;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Primary
@Repository("testDAO")
public class TestDAO {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

TestSOA.java

```
package soa;
import dao.TestDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service("testSOA")
public class TestSOA {
    @Autowired
    private TestDAO testDAO;
    public String getMessage() {
        return testDAO.getMessage();
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package bean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import soa.TestSOA;
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld")
@SessionScoped
@Controller
public class HelloWorld implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private TestSOA testSOA;
    public String getMessage() {
        return testSOA.getMessage();
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao, soa, bean"/>

</beans>
```

Then in index.xhtml

```
Message:<h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.message}"/>
```

I don't understand, I thought I did everything I was suppose to.
web.xml has the ContextLoaderListener declared. I've tried using CDI and other Spring methods and manually wiring with applicationContext.xml. *Nothing...*

My guess is I'm not getting some fundamental principal concerning Spring or injection.
I'm using Java 1.6, Spring 3.1.1, and Tomcat 7.0.34.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<context:annotation-config />` to your `applicationContext.xml` before `<context:component-scan>` to enable annotation based Spring configuration. See [Annotation-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) section in Spring reference.

Comment: No, no effect, it's still not injecting (or it is, but it's injecting null?). Thank you for the advice just the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the  provided, to inject a Spring managed bean into JSF managed bean, you have to be able to delegate resolution of managed beans to an external resolver.

Check your `web.xml` for `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener`
and

`faces-config.xml` for `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver`.

See also http://deevodavis.wordpress.com/injecting-spring-beans-into-jsf-2-managedbean-classes/